# connection refused from jena fuseki

Tags: fuseki

I'm trying to READ my data from localhost jena fuseki with the SPARQL query service on the internet like this one
http://factforge.net/sparql
this is my query

```
select * where { 
service <http://localhost:3030/blibiografi/sparql>{
    ?s ?p ?o .}
limit 10
```

. but unfortunately I get an error message like below.

```
Error 500: error
Query evaluation error: Connect to localhost:3030 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) (HTTP status 500)
```

can i pull data directly from jena fuseki directly with query or not?
or is there a service where i can upload my graph ontology and perform read and update operations on it?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is related to encountering a "Connection refused" error while attempting to use the FactForge query service to query your local data, it's important to understand that this error is likely occurring because Fuseki is only running on your local machine and is not accessible from FactForge.

In this situation, the solution is to use the Fuseki Web interface on your local machine, as it will allow you to query your dataset directly. You've already identified the correct Fuseki Web interface URL, so you can access the Fuseki UI by navigating to `http://localhost:3030/#/dataset/<datasetname>/query` in your browser. This approach should resolve the "Connection refused" error, as it bypasses the need to access FactForge and instead interacts with your local Fuseki instance.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for your feedback. I am new to answering questions on Stack Overflow (not new to reading them) and still have to get used to it. I have edited my answer above according to your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Sorry that I cannot upvote this as "useful", simply for lack of knowledge of the technical details on my side. But it now looks clearly like an answer. Have fun.